# How to disable the "task switcher" button and notifications in android 3.0

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

All help appcreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Smash your tablet with a sledgehammer.

Otherwise, you cannot disable the "recent tasks" list or notifications, except perhaps via custom firmware. The system bar is a permanent screen feature on Android 3.x.